# Perform doOn<...> even if unsubscribed

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have an `Observable` that can emit events in some time after subscribing (e.g. an `Observable` from the `Retrofit`). The subscription to this `Observable` is strictly `View-related`, so when the `View` is destroyed I'm unsubscribing from the `Observable`. I want to perform some actions in `doOnNext` even if I unsubscribe the `Subscription`.

Example code:

```
final Observable<String> observable = ...; // will emit an event in some time in future
final Subscription subscription =
        observable.doOnNext(new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) {
                //this should be called even if the subscription is unsubscribed
            }
        }).subscribe();
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Is there a way to make sure `doOn<something>` will be called even if the `Subscription` is unsubscribed?

**EDIT:**

Let me give you a bit clearer example:

```
final Observable<List<GithubRepo>> observable = getGithubReposFromApi();
subscription = observable
        .doOnNext(githubRepos -> cacheGithubReposInDb(githubRepos))
        .subscribe(githubRepos -> displayGithubReposInCurrentActivity(githubRepos));
```

And in `Activity's` `onDestroy`:

```
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Now... If `githubRepos` were received after the `Activity` has been destroyed, the result wouldn't be cached in the database. And I would like it to be.

Comment: This seems weird. Since `Observable` should not emit items after `unsubscribed`, how to call `doOnNext`?

Comment: maybe you didn't understand me correctly. I know it won't emit items after unsubscribed. I'm looking for a workaround for that exact fact. I WANT it to be called.

Comment: Then don't unsubscribe the subscription in onDestroy. Make it live outside the activity and tie it to some other lifecycle event.

Comment: @akarnokd but I want to do it :) because e.g. `displayGithubReposInCurrentActivity` will not be viable after the activity is destroyed. Using `subscription.unsubscribe()` seems to be much cleaner than checking if `displayGithubReposInCurrentActivity` is viable. More so, keeping it subscribed after the `Activity` is destroyed could lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you want the computation to run but want to cut off the Activity-dependent subscriber. You can publish() the sequence and subscribe to it. When unsubscribed, the original sequence will still go on:

```
ConnectableObservable<T> co = observable
.doOnNext(githubRepos -> cacheGithubReposInDb(githubRepos))
.publish();

Subscription s = co.subscribe(githubRepos ->
    displayGithubReposInCurrentActivity(githubRepos));

co.connect();

// ...

s.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't make myself clear enough, because tbh your answer is not really relevant to my question. Why don't you check my new edit to the question. I think it makes it much more understandable.

Comment: Keep in mind though, that - just like with `autoConnect` - this will keep the upstream subscription around indefinitely. At least unless you keep a reference to the `Subscription` returned by `co.connect()` and `unsubscribe` from that later. But at this point you could just as well have used two `Subscribers`...

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do one of two things:

1.) Just have two `Subscribers`: one for `View` related stuff and one for the other side-effects that you are currently handling in `doOnNext`. To still have only one upstream subscription you could use:

```
Observable sharedObservable = observable.replay().refCount();
```

or maybe just

```
Observable sharedObservable = observable.share();
// which is the same as       observable.publish().refCount();
```

2.) Use

```
Observable observableThatWillNeverTrulyUnsubscribe = observable.doOnNext(/* your doOnNext */).publish().autoConnect();
```

Now, when your `Subscriber` subscribes to `observableThatWillNeverTrulyUnsubscribe` it will subscribe to `observable` and will start emitting items. However, when the `Subscriber` unsubscribes, it will **not** unsubscribe upwards and thus `doOnNext` will continue to receive items.

I think I would prefer to first option as with the second you are giving up any possibility of ever stopping the work of `observable`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The second idea of yours is pretty dirty. Leaving a subscription subscribed "forever" doesn't seem like the best idea. I have already thought about your first idea, but I had to discard it because it forces the "recipient" of the `Observable` to make sure that both `Subscribers` correctly `subscribe` and `unsubscribe`. And there's seems to be no particular moment for the other `subscription` (the one that would manage `doOnNext`) to be `unsubscribed`. I would like the solution to be completely transparent for the "recipient" of the `Observable`.

Comment: Yeah, of course it's dirty! :-) But I think you can't have it both ways: either you have an active Subscription or you don't and if you do have an active Subscription you are also responsible for unsubscribing. But you could add a `take(1)` before the `publish()` in the second solution - this should also make sure that `observable` is stopped after emitting one item.